# Константно-квадратный UI элемент в Unity. Unity 5

Tags: c#, вёрстка, unity3d

Необходимо в Unity сделать Image со свойством `Image Type = Sliced` при любом разрешении экрана, квадратным.

Так же рассматривал такие варианты, как:

1. `Image Type = Simple` с включённым `Preserve Aspect`, но результат меня не удовлетворил, так как элемент остаётся визуально квадратным, но для других элементов он является прямоугольным (зависит от разрешения экрана)
2. Использовал некоторые вариации с `Aspect Ratio Fitter` и так далее, никаких результатов получено не было.

Какие есть решения данной проблемы?

Заранее благодарен за любой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно поставить анкоры в одну точку, а не растягивать его углы по канвасу.

Тогда элемент не изменит свою форму.

Есть еще способ програмно проверять соотношение сторон высоты и ширины в апдейте. И подганять толи высоту под ширину (то ли наоборот) если неправильное соотношение.

Comment: Согласен с вами. Но тут возникает один момент.
Если использовать разные разрешения экранов, то квадрат на них будет иметь разный размер.

Comment: конфигурируйте канвас и будет вам дзен.